# IIS7.5 400 Bad request when a URL includes character :

Tags: iis, http-status-code-400

I am using ARR and ISAPI with IIS7.5.
Whenever forwarding URL including specific character :
400 Bad request occurs.
How can I solve it?

I guess there is no problem in ARR and ISAPI because no problem in development server(same Env as operating server) it only occurs in operating server.

Answer (score 2):

By default IIS 7.5 rejecects certain characters in the path -- the default is the follwing comma separated list: `<,>,*,%,&,:,\\`. If a request hits that list it will return a http 400 error as the request is bad insofar as the server is configured. See this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) and [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a little background. Specifically, you'll likely want to update the httpRuntime configuration to something like:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"
             requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\"
             />
```

Comment: How can I use requestValidationMode in ASP2.0?

Comment: IIS 7.5 runs everything through the managed pipeline, just add it to the web.config file in the folder.

Comment: It did not work on ASP2.0 when i added it web.config. I works on ASP4.0. Is there other options working on ASP2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The `:` character is only permitted in URLs as part of an IPv6 address. Either encode it as `%3A`, or don't use it.

You can find the reference in [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)